# Site is not working in chrome, but works in FF and IE

Tags: google-chrome, iis, ssl, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

Strange behavior.

This site: ****

Works in firefox and internet explorer, despite the insecure certificate.

But doesn't work at all in Chrome, and says `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`

Anyone else getting this? I've tried it on 3 different computers already, and can't figure out why Chrome doesn't see it.  Also, I can't get it to work on an iphone either.

How do I get this to work in all browsers, am I doing something wrong? Someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get to the site over HTTP, but not over HTTPS (tested in Chrome 38.0.2125.122 and Safari 8.0). Does this help?

Comment: http it does work, but https is where the problem is. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: Well then, the HTTPS problem is also extended to Safari and the Android Browser (just tested)

Comment: That explains why it won't work in my iphone, but still dont know why it works in firefox and internet explorer

Comment: I do not have Firefox or IE, but 2 quick tests on [Browserling](https://browserling.com) also fail to show the page over HTTPS (although it is shown via HTTP).

Comment: IE11 doesn't see this page either. Web server is either not configured or wrongly configured to use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Microsoft Update KB2992611 is causing the problem.  See this article: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2848574/operating-systems/microsoft-botches-kb-2992611-schannel-patch-tls-alert-code-40-slow-sql-server-block-iis-sites.html

Uninstall the patch solved the problem, but I am not sure of the right steps to take to fix what the patch was intending to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems begin lately with HTTPS pages of two websites on Win server 2012.

On most computers it works fine.

But in some computers:

- In IE FF or Safari its OK,
- But in Chrome or new Opera it raise error:
  "This webpage is not available
  The webpage at [my https url] might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
  In Chrome it show also: "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED"

This failed requests not appear in the IIS logs.

Comment: Check your firewall settings on port 443

Comment: Thanks RealWorldCoder. The firewall settings are probably OK, since for most computers and browsers it works fine.

Comment: And I have update:
It looks that in the last days, the HTTPS problem on my server website is solved.

I assume that this fixed when Chrome version updated form 38 to 39 in Chrome & Opera.

Comment: Here is UserAgents in PC that I tested before an after the problem fixed:

*Chrome*

At 11/20/2014: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36

At 11/26/2014: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36

*Opera*

At 11/20/2014: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36 OPR/25.0.1614.71

At 11/26/2014: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36 OPR/26.0.1656.24